# Back button not loading page content - JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am building a hybrid app on jquery mobile and i wanna use back buttons to navigate between different pages.

I have created the back button and it DOES load the url of the last page, but it doesn't refresh the page content (it keeps showing the same page ie: the button doesn't realize the function)

Looking through the questions previously asked about back button - jquery mobile I can't find one exposing a problem of page loading (cause as I said the button gets the right url but doesn't load the page content)

NOTE: i am using IBM Mobile First

```
<a href="#loginPage" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button"
            id="mainPageBackBtn" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"
            data-corners="false">Button</a>
```

(I wanna move from main page --> login page)

Comment: Loading cached pages is the default functionality for a back button. Did you have reason to expect otherwise with this arrangement?

Comment: when clicking on the button, it actually shows the right url in the navigation bar but it doesn't refresh the page. please tell me if that's not clear enough.

Comment: @isherwood I guess you didn't get what he said, he made a button called 'back button', it is not the default back button

Comment: I understand that, but the default behavior for almost any 'back' history state action is to load the cached page.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML button tag is working fine in JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/a8pzr7gt/6/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="mainPage" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#loginPage" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button"
            id="mainPageBackBtn" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"
            data-corners="false">Button</a>
        <h5>Main Page</h5>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>This is Main Page</h2>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="loginPage" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        
          <a href="#mainPage" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button"
            id="mainPageBackBtn" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"
            data-corners="false">Button</a>
        <h5>Login Page</h5>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>This is Login Page</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe try check you tag Id is correctly assigned?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using data-ajax="false" here:

```
<a href="#loginPage" data-ajax="false" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button"
        id="mainPageBackBtn" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"
        data-corners="false">Button</a>
```